# How to only match before the first dot?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex.

```
^((?!example).)*$#Subdomain is reserved (example).
```

I would like to validate `<subdomain>.example.org`. However, since the domain name contains `example`, a match is occurring.

The validation should not match when the address is `www.example.org`

The validation should match when the address is `example.example.org`

Comment: Should `example.somethingelse.com` match? How about `somethingelse.example.org`? How about `some.thing.example.org`?

Comment: What about just `example.com` (with no subdomain)?

Comment: example.somethingelse.com should match. somethingelse.example.org should not.

Comment: for some reason I had splitting in my head when really i just needed to match the start with a dot. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the escape character from the period

```
^(example)\..*$
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a simple

```
^example\.
```

is enough. Or use string methods, depending on your language:

```
url.indexOf('example.') === 0
```

If input such as `example.org` is also possible, you can use

```
^example\..+\.
```

to force the appearance of two dots. But this would still fail for `example.co.uk`. It depends on your input.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way might be to break it up into two:

1. `^.+\.example\.org$`
2. `^(www)?\.example\.org$`

If 1) matches and 2) does not, it's a subdomain of `example.org`; otherwise, it's not. (Although `www` technically is a subdomain, but you understand.)